Date Binding issue in CRM Analytics
I'm currently working on a dashboard project in CRM Analytics, where the goal is to filter one date field based on the selection of another date field within the same dataset. Right now, I'm applying a filter from one date field to another, and here’s the query I'm using:
"sourceFilters": {
            "dataset": {
                "filters": [
                    [
                        "Date_1",
                        [
                            "{{cell(Date_2.result, 0, \"min\").asObject()}}",
                            null
                        ],
                        "between"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },

This binding selects the minimum value of the date_2 epoch, with the expectation that date_1 will only display data after this minimum date from the date_2 filter.
While this binding functions well when the date_2 result is a specific month, it fails to operate correctly when date_2 covers a broader time period, such as a quarter or a week.
Should I use other way to bind two date filter together? Or is there other better way to achieve the expectation?
Thanks!
